# Mysterious segfaults when overriding pthread functions on glibc but not on musl

Tags: c, pthreads, glibc, dynamic-linking, musl

I'm trying to override `pthread_create` and `pthread_exit`. The overrides should call the originals.

I can override `pthread_create`, and it appears to works as long as I exit my main thread with `pthread_exit(0);`. If I don't it segfaults.

If I even attempt to override `pthread_exit`, I get segfaults.

My setup is below:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > test.c <<EOF
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thr(void *Arg)
{
    printf("i=%d\n", (int)(intptr_t)Arg);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    putchar('\n');
    pthread_t tids[4];
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof tids / sizeof tids[0]; i++){
        pthread_create(tids+i, 0, thr, (void*)(intptr_t)i);

    }
    pthread_exit(0); //SEGFAULTS if this isn't here
    return 0;
}
EOF
cat > pthread_override.c <<EOF

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if 1
__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
int pthread_create(
        pthread_t *restrict Thr, 
        pthread_attr_t const *Attr,
        void *(*Fn) (void *), 
        void *Arg
        )
{
    int r;
    int (*real_pthread_create)(
        pthread_t *restrict Thr, 
        pthread_attr_t const *Attr,
        void *(*Fn) (void *), 
        void *Arg
    ) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
    printf("CREATE BEGIN: %p\n", (void*)Thr);
    r = real_pthread_create(Thr, Attr, Fn, Arg);
    printf("CREATE END: %p\n", (void*)Thr);
    return r;
}
#endif

#if 0 
//SEGFAULTS if this is allowed
__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
_Noreturn
void pthread_exit(void *Retval)
{
    __attribute__((__noreturn__)) void (*real_pthread_exit)( void *Arg);
    real_pthread_exit = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_exit");
    printf("%p\n", (void*)real_pthread_exit);
    puts("EXIT");
    real_pthread_exit(Retval);
}
#endif
EOF

: ${CC:=gcc}
$CC -g -fpic pthread_override.c -shared -o pthread.so -ldl
$CC -g test.c $PWD/pthread.so -ldl -lpthread 
./a.out
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and what the reason for the segfaults is?

The problems completely disappear if I substitute musl-gcc for gcc.

Comment: Interesting. The problems completely disappear if I substitute musl-gcc for gcc.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from one of the segfaults?

Comment: @AndrewHenle `#1  0x00007fba3b07181d in pthread_create (Thr=0x7ffcb455f540, Attr=0x0, Fn=0x4007b6 <thr>, Arg=0x0) at pthread_override.c:24
#2  0x000000000040082a in main () at test.c:18` if I compile `pthread_exit`
and `#1  0x00007f024ec1b7ad in pthread_create (Thr=0x7ffc46ec8c00, Attr=0x0, Fn=0x400766 <thr>, Arg=0x0) at pthread_override.c:24
#2  0x00000000004007d7 in main () at test.c:18`  if I don't `pthread_exit` from main.

Comment: Override?  In C?  Sounds kinda OO-ish?

Comment: Can you try compiling with `-Wl,--wrap=pthread_create` instead, and implement `__wrap_pthread_create()` by calling `__real_pthread_create()`?  That's the more usual way of doing this kind of interposition that I have seen.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That's what I tried first. Didn't work so I changed it to the dlsym version. I'll try it again with both glibc and musl.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. Got the __wrap version working with both musl and glibc. I guess the segfaults probably has to do with symbol versioning, which musl doesn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and what the reason for the segfaults is?

It's complicated.

You are probably on Linux/x86_64, and being hit by [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14932). See also [this original report](http://marc.info/?l=glibc-alpha&m=98313801301771&w=2).

**Update:**

It turns out symbol versions have *nothing* to do with the problem (on `x86_64`, there are *no* multiple versions of `pthread_create` or `pthread_exit`).

The issue is that `gcc` is configured to pass `--as-needed` to the linker.

When you link with `pthread_exit` `#ifdef`ed out, the `a.out` binary gets `pthread_exit` from `libpthread.so.0`, which is recorded as a `NEEDED` shared library:

```
readelf -d a.out | grep libpthread
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
```

When you `#ifdef` `pthread_exit` in, none of the real `libpthread.so.0` symbols are needed anymore (the references are satisfied by `pthread.so`):

```
readelf -d a.out | grep libpthread
# no output!
```

This then causes the `dlsym` to fail (there is *no* next symbol to return -- `pthread.so` defines the *only one*):

```
Breakpoint 2, __dlsym (handle=0xffffffffffffffff, name=0x7ffff7bd8881 "pthread_create") at dlsym.c:56
56  dlsym.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  __dlsym (handle=0xffffffffffffffff, name=0x7ffff7bd8881 "pthread_create") at dlsym.c:56
pthread_create (Thr=0x7fffffffdc80, Attr=0x0, Fn=0x40077d <thr>, Arg=0x0) at pthread_override.c:17
17      int (*real_pthread_create)(
Value returned is $1 = (void *) 0x0
```

Solution: add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the main application link line before `-lpthread`.

P.S. I am reminded about [rule #3 from David Agans' book](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse474/17wi/pdfs/lectures/Debugging-Rules.pdf) (which I highly recommend): **Quit thinking and look**.

Comment: A 17 year old bug. Really inspires confidence in the whole thing. :D Is there a workaround? glibc has dlsymv. Perhaps something relying on that?

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, I ended up using `dlvsym` to work around this problem. The complication with it is that different architectures have different versioned symbols, so if you need to support more than just `x86_64`, some additional logic is necessary to select the right version.

Comment: @PSkocik I've updated the answer. The problem likely have nothing to do with symbol versioning.

Answer (score 2):

You can instead compile with `-Wl,--wrap=pthread_create`, and implement `__wrap_pthread_create()` by calling `__real_pthread_create()`.

That's the more usual way of doing this kind of interposition.

Comment: They way I successfully did the __wrap thing is I made a library supplying the wrap function and then compiled and linked with `gcc main.c $PWD/mylib.so -lpthread -Wl,--wrap=pthread_create,--wrap=pthread_exit`. I'm not happy with this solution because it requires the user of the wrapper to know the wrapping is going on and pass the `--wrap` switches. I'd like a solution where the user doesn't need to pass that extra stuff. If you know how to do it, please share it and I'll reaccept. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Interposing with `--wrap` doesn't actually interpose the symbol and only *some* of the calls are intercepted when existing shared libraries are used.